# Copy first n hex of a file

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file

You can output the first `n` hex bytes of a file in Linux with `xdd` (`xdd -ps`, etc)

How would one do this on Windows, though? Is there a way?

Comment: take a look at this Question >>> Extract the first 50 bytes of a file using Powershell - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766774/extract-the-first-50-bytes-of-a-file-using-powershell <<< you can convert the bytes into hex chars fairly directly.

Comment: the Answer posted by user1686 shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple string of hex numbers:

```
[BitConverter]::ToString((Get-Content $file -Encoding Byte -TotalCount $nbytes))
```

If you want to get a "traditional" hexdump of a file:

```
Format-Hex $file
```

<sub>Both found via google.</sub>